# Three.js - Set rotation of object from normalized directions of the X, Y and Z-Axis

Tags: matrix, rotation, three.js, normals, euler-angles

From a model file object definition the placement a new object is given by a `location` (a point in space) and the normalized directions of the X-Axis, the Y-Axis and the Z-Axis.

How can i translate this to a `THREE.Euler` so i can rotate my object correctly in space.

So the axes are off type `THREE.Vector3`.
If the new object is aligned with the `world` the values would be:

```
xAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );

yAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );

zAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
```

But if for example the whole local UCS of the object is rotated 180 degrees ( or `Math.PI` ) around the `zAxis` they would look like this:

```
xAxis = new THREE.Vector3( -1, 0, 0 );

yAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, -1, 0 );

zAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
```

So I need to do something like this:

```
var object3D = new THREE.Object3D();

object3D.position = location;

var euler = new THREE.Euler();

euler.setFromNormalizedAxes( xAxis, yAxis, zAxis );

object3D.rotation = euler;
```

Or create a rotation matrix from those axes:

```
var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

rotationMatrix.setFromNormalizedAxes( xAxis, yAxis, zAxis );

object3D.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix( rotationMatrix, "XYZ" );
```

I am not so good yet with these rotation matrices and euler rotations...

Comment: You are way off-base. See http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/ for a description of what the normal matrix is, and what it is used for.

Comment: @WestLangley Okay, you are right, I misinterpreted the function of `_normalMatrix` totally. I changed the question. When I was digging and I ran into the normalMatrix it looked like this:
1 0 0 
0 1 0
0 0 1
Which is exactly like the X, Y and Z-Axis definitions which is why i assumed it had to do with normalized UCS axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you gave, the answer would be

```
object.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(

    new THREE.Matrix4( -1,  0,  0,  0,
                        0, -1,  0,  0,
                        0,  0,  1,  0,
                        0,  0,  0,  1 )

);
```

The columns of the upper 3x3 of the `Matrix4` are the new x-, y-, and z-axes.

You could set `object.rotation` instead. It does not matter.

three.js r.66

Comment: It worked out perfectly. I tried that before but I did something wrong I guess. Thanks for your help!