# Three.js - How to use the rotation matrix correctly?

Tags: matrix, three.js, 3d, rotation, axis

After days of research, the rotation matrices of Three.js are not behaving like I expect, and I don’t know what I am missing.

I need to define the rotation of each object in my scene in the form of three direction unit vectors, each one describing the direction of one local axis. Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988969/three-js-set-rotation-of-object-from-normalized-directions-of-the-x-y-and-z-a), I have created a simple scene with two axes. I am applying rotations to the second one, while the first one (in the center) shows the global coordinates. You can see the scene [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-use-the-rotation-matrix-correctly/20766).

In my case, the default direction vectors for an object are the following. These values mean that there is no rotation applied on the object.

```
Axis x: (1,0,0)
Axis y: (0,1,0)
Axis z: (0,0,1)
```

Following this criteria, I have tried to rotate the object 90º on the Y axis counter clockwise (so that the Z axis ends up pointing in the direction of the current x Axis):

```
const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
rotationMatrix.set( 
  0  ,0  ,-1 ,0
 ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0
 ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0
 ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1
 );
axes.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix);
```

The first issue that I have encountered is that the rotation is not made in the direction I expected; in this case, it is made clockwise instead of counter clockwise. I can fix this inverting the local rotation after applying the rotation matrix:

```
axes.rotation.x *= -1;
axes.rotation.y *= -1;
axes.rotation.z *= -1;
```

So far, so good, and this works for rotations in all the axes. Nonetheless, there might be objects that have rotations in multiple axes. For example, I want to rotate this object not only 90º on the Y axis, but also 90º on the (global) Z axis. The result that I expect is an object that has the the local X pointing to the global -Z, the local Y pointing to the global X and the local Z pointing to the global -Y.

```
const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
rotationMatrix.set( 
 0  ,0  ,-1 ,0
,1  ,0  ,0  ,0
,0  ,-1 ,0  ,0
,0  ,0  ,0  ,1
);
axes.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix);
axes.rotation.x *= -1;
axes.rotation.y *= -1;
axes.rotation.z *= -1;
```

But [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-use-the-rotation-matrix-correctly/20766) is what I get. Is there something I missed about the rotation matrix?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Done! Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Investigating deeper in that direction (and with the help of a mathematician friend) I have discovered that the vectors I have form the 4x4 direction matrix, which is the inverse matrix of the 4x4 rotation matrix. A call to [Matrix4.getInverse](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix4.getInverse) was the solution to define rotations using direction vectors.

```
const x = transform[xAxis];
const y = transform[yAxis];
const z = transform[zAxis];
const directionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
directionMatrix.set( 
 x[0] ,x[1] ,x[2] ,0
,y[0] ,y[1] ,y[2] ,0
,z[0] ,z[1] ,z[2] ,0
,0    ,0    ,0    ,1
);

rotationMatrix.getInverse(directionMatrix);
return rotationMatrix;
```

This was also posted in the Three.js forum.